# VSCode Unable to import from requirement despite Command line being successful with pip3 install requirements.txt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, requirements.txt, python-3.11

so im trying to run a python script to download Zoom recordings all at once.
For refrence I will link the GitHub Repository that i am using.
https://github.com/ricardorodrigues-ca/zoom-recording-downloader

I have python3.11 installed on windows 11. After cloning the repository, I installed the `requirements.txt` file in the correct directory with the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`. the download was succesfull.

However VSCode is Showing `Import "tqdm" could not be resolved from source.` PylancereportMissingModuleSource etc.. (tqdm is one of the requirements along with others displaying the same error). I've tried installing them one by one, and it returns with requirement already satisfied.

If i try running the script anyways, this is what returns.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yisro\Desktop\zoom-recording-downloader\zoom-recording-downloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tqdm import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to solve this.

I tried the commands above, and i was expecting to get the return of the script downloading the videos one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use command `pip list` to check the installation is successful.

Then, have you checked whether your installation environment is consistent with the running file environment?

You can use "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct interpreter.

You can use command `pip install tqdm` to solve it.

Comment: pip list                                           Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2022.12.7
charset-normalizer 3.0.1
colorama           0.4.6
idna               3.4
pytz               2022.7.1
six                1.16.0
urllib3            1.26.14

i have my python interpiter to python3.11 64bit C:\python.exe

Comment: You can use command `pip install tqdm` to solve it.